# Как загрузить zip файл с сайта, а затем его распаковать?

Tags: c#, zip

Скачиваю во временную папку архив tempp.zip

```
 System.Net.WebClient miner = new System.Net.WebClient();
 load1.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http:/site.pro/tempp.zip"), 
 Path.GetTempPath() + "\\tempp.zip"); // Скачиваем в %temp%
 while (load1.IsBusy) { } // дождаться завершения загрузки
```

А потом пытаюсь заэкстрактить

```
  ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\tempp.zip", Path.GetTempPath());
```

Но архив не хочет распаковываться ,как быть ?

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске. Ошибку какую пишет?  Проверяли существование файла по указанному пути?

Comment: Ааааа! Мои глаза! `while (load1.IsBusy) { }` Думаю, ошибка состоит в том, что процессор сгорел.

Comment: без этого программа завершается раньше ,чем заканчивается скачивание архива

Comment: Необработанное исключение: System.NotImplementedException: Метод или операция не реализована.
   в System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String zipPath, String extractPath) в C:\Users\avtor\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\System\IO\Compression\ZipFile.cs:строка 12
   в ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\avtor\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:строка 26

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников: Ну так используйте не-Async-функцию для загрузки.

Comment: `await load1.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http:/site.pro/tempp.zip"), 
 Path.GetTempPath() + "\\tempp.zip");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае надо было подключить библиотку using System.IO.Compression; из сборки

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример работы через `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string downloadUrl = "http://www.phantastike.com/agni_yoga/simfoniya_1/zip/";
        string pathToFile = @"D:\simfoniya.zip";

        Task.Run(async () => await DownloadFile(downloadUrl, pathToFile))
            .ContinueWith((result) => UnzipFile(pathToFile));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task DownloadFile(string downloadUrl, string pathToFile)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(downloadUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result)
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
                fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
            {
                var totalRead = 0L;
                var totalReads = 0L;
                var buffer = new byte[8192];
                var isMoreToRead = true;

                do
                {
                    var read = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read == 0)
                    {
                        isMoreToRead = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);

                        totalRead += read;
                        totalReads += 1;

                        if (totalReads % 10 == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Загружаем файл. Загружено: {totalRead:n0}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (isMoreToRead);

                Console.WriteLine($"Готово! Файл загружен.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void UnzipFile(string pathToFile)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(pathToFile))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Указанный файл не найден.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Начинаем распаковку...");

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(pathToFile, Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToFile));

        Console.WriteLine("Готово!");
    }

}
```